# Can someone find the problem in my code related to IF STATEMENT in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int max_of_four(int q, int w, int e, int r)
{
    int x;
    if( q > w &&  q > e &&  q > r)
        {int x = q;}
    else if( w > q &&  w > e && w > r)
        {int x = w;}
    else if( e > w &&  e > q &&  e > r)
        {int x = e;}
    else if( r > w &&  r > e &&  r > q)
        {int x = r;}
    else{x = 0;}   
    return x;
}
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    cout << max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

it always outputs 0, no matter what the input is.

I suppose the I am missing something in the `if statement` condition, someone please help!

Comment: you redefine x in the if, you shadow the pprevious one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the if's `int x = q;` defines a new variable `x` and does *not* modify the `x` you return later.

You probably just want `x = q;` to assign a new value to `x`. This also applies to the other if's.

Or you could skip the assignment alltogether:

```
int max_of_four(int q, int w, int e, int r)
{
    if( q > w &&  q > e &&  q > r)
        { return q; }
    else if( w > q &&  w > e && w > r)
        { return w; }
    else if( e > w &&  e > q &&  e > r)
        { return e; }
    else if( r > w &&  r > e &&  r > q)
        { return r; }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have `C++11` or later, then [`std::max()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) can take an *initializer list* as its argument(s):

```cpp
int max_of_four(int q, int w, int e, int r)
{
    return std::max({ q, w, e, r }); // Need to #include <algorithm> for std::max
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from redefinition of variable x, your test conditions, could be trimmed, are insufficient when values of q, w, e or r are same. Also logically the return value should be either of the four variables but it should never return a zero.

```
   int max_of_four(int q, int w, int e, int r)
   {
       int max = q;
       if (w > max ) max = w;
       if (e > max ) max = e;
       if (r > max ) max = r;
       return max;
   }
```